# Почему не срабатывает условие !=?

Tags: python, aiogram, бот, telegram

Написал код бота модератора для тг-канала, который должен удалять комментарии подписчиков, содержащие слово из словаря. При этом пропускать любые комментарии администратора, в т.ч. содержащие любое слово из словаря. В итоге удаляет все комментарии. id админа получаю из файла cfg.py. Подскажите, в чем ошибка кода?

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def mess_handler(message: types.Message):
    text = message.text.lower()
    while str(message.from_user.id) != cfg.ADMIN_ID:
        for word in cfg.WORDS:
            if word in text:
                await message.delete()
```

А в таком варианте кода, бот вообще не удаляет любые комментарии:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def mess_handler(message: types.Message):
    text = message.text.lower()
    for word in cfg.WORDS:
        if word in text:
            if message.from_id != cfg.ADMIN_ID:
                pass
            else:
                await message.delete()
```

Такой вариант кода тоже не работает и комментарии не удаляет - TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def mess_handler(message: types.Message):
    text = message.text.lower()
    for word in cfg.WORDS and str(message.from_user.id) != '@***':
        if word in text:
            await message.delete()
```

Comment: Во втором случае `message.from_id == cfg.ADMIN_ID` должно быть. И надо проверить что там и действительно ли `message.from_id` возвращает id пользователя

Comment: Попробуй заменить ```message.from_user.id``` на ```message.chat.id```

Comment: Оба варианта с предлагаемой заменой не работают

Comment: для чего у вас `and` в форе в третьем варианте? из-за него создается `bool` объект и выкидывается эта ошибка: `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`

Comment: Я так записал условие: слово из словаря и id не админа - удаление.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу предложить "грубый", но рабочий вариант:

```
mat = ['один', 'два', 'три', 'пять']

@dp.message_handler()
async def process_start(message: types.Message):
    if str(message.from_user.id) != cfg.ADMIN_ID and any(x in message.text.lower() for x in mat):
        await message.reply("Не матерись!!!")
        await message.delete()
    else:
        pass
```

"грубый" - потому, что могут быть ложные срабатывания, к примеру "`два`дцать", "о`пять`". Нужно это учитывать при создании словаря с нецензурными словами. Но не стоит забывать про категорию пользователей, которые будут маскировать мат, печатая часть букв в английской раскладке, вместо `О` писать `0`, добавлять спецсимволы и так далее. Поэтому это простой и грубый метод фильтрации мата

Comment: К сожалению, опять не работает в плане игнорирования комментариев админа.
Как я понял, ошибка кроется в выражении if str(message.from_user.id) != cfg.ADMIN_ID, но не понимаю в чем она. Написал print, вывел id сообщения и админа, получилось, что когда я сам пишу сообщения с вэб-версии Телеги, то мои message.from_user.id мой id всегда разные, а условие != всегда True. И не важно, комментарий оставляет админ или какой-то пользователь.

Comment: так покажите что у вас скрывается за `cfg.ADMIN_ID`, код полностью рабочий, который я приложил, проблема именно с вашим `cfg.ADMIN_ID` и можно только догадываться что вы там храните

Comment: cfg.ADMIN_ID находится в файле cfg.py, вот содержимое файла:

CHANNEL_URL = 'https://t.me/*****',

CHANNEL_ID = '@*****',

CHAT_ID = '@*****',
ADMIN_ID = '222222'       #Id администратора тг канала,
WORDS = ["мат"]

Уточню, что типы данных int/str для переменных пробовал все, поэтому не в них дело

Comment: `id` пользователя, который получаете через `message.from_user.id` не может быть разным, это уникальный номер и он не динамический

Comment: Сейчас добавил строку print(message.from_user.id, cfg.ADMIN_ID), в терминале получил два разных числа: 10******24 12*****84. Первое 10 разрядов, второе 9.

Comment: вот и присвойте переменной `ADMIN_ID` в файле `cfg` значение `10******24`

Comment: Да, теперь заработало, спасибо!) Но вот в чем вопрос: id админа получил через "сторонний" бот @getmyid_bot и получил 9-значный id, а message.from_user.id получал через print в коде своего бота и id получил 10-значный. Почему разница в id?

Comment: тут не подскажу почему вам тот бот выдал такой id. Ну и раз на ваш вопрос вы получили ответ, то можете отметить его как решение ))

Comment: Я тут первый раз, отметить как решение - это нажать галку на вопросе, верно?

Comment: да, на галочку - это отметит ответ как решение, также дополнительно можете нажать стрелочку вверх, чтобы "лайкнуть" ответ. Вижу, что вы нажали галочку, но не на моем ответе )))

Comment: Сделал! Кстати, ваш код работает без ошибок, но заглавные буквы в строчные не переводит)

Comment: при проверке все буквы делаются строчным, исходя из чего вы сделали вывод, что не переводит?

Comment: @Andrey ну и повторюсь, что вы не мой ответ отметили как решение ))

Comment: При запуске вашего кода PyCharm выделяет цветом "x in message.text.lower()" и пишет SyntaxError: unmatched ')'. Я добавил скобку, получилось "any((x in message.text.lower())" и заработало, но заглавные буквы не обрабатывает.
Отметил решение еще раз, все верно?

Comment: поправил ответ, у меня там скобка дважды прожалась видимо, когда печатал, должно быть так `any(x in message.text.lower() for x in mat)`

Answer (score 0):

Если ошибка в сравнении в 1 варианте то просто перед сравнением напиши print(message.from_user.id, cfg.ADMIN_ID) просто их сравни глазами и на всякий посмотри что выводит print(type(message.from_user.id), type(cfg.ADMIN_ID)) (Проверка типа переменных)
просто если где ошибка то только в сравнении.
Да и while тебе зачем проверяй через if или бот отключится сразу ?
Есть альтернатива либо

```
while True:
    if str(message.from_user.id) != cfg.ADMIN_ID:
        break
    for word in cfg.WORDS:
            if word in text:
                await message.delete()
            # Если надо добавь
            else:
                break
```

Или просто добавить

```
if str(message.from_user.id) != cfg.ADMIN_ID:
        break
```

Да и как ты открываешь файлы через open() ?
Просто если первое сообщение было сделано не от админа то while не будет проверять ещё раз вроде как.

Comment: К сожалению не работает, тут вообще пишет 'unreachable code'